# OnTextChanged chamado várias vezes - autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uns 50 TextBox com desse tipo:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_DetImovel0" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_DetImovel0_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_DetImovel1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_DetImovel0_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_DetImovel2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_DetImovel0_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Tenho uma função em javascript que muda o valor da TextBox quando ele seleciona uma cor (Color Picker)

O problema é que em modo debug eu percebo que essa função "txt_DetImovel0_TextChanged" esta sendo chamada uma para cada campo! mesmo que o .js só esteja mudando 1 campo. (Coloquei um alert('teste'); e só aparece realmente uma vez, porém quando vou debugando vejo que é chamado várias vezes.

**Dúvidas:**

Existe como eu saber ou monitorar quem esta disparando essa função? visto que no modo debug só vejo as ações do code behind.

Como fazer para somente o campo que tiver o valor modificado pelo .js chame realmente essa função.?

*OBS: Descobri que quando tenho o autopostback=true ele realmente vai enviar para cada campo, mesmo que eu só tenha mudado o valor de 1 campo!!! isso é um BUG do .NET ?*

a imagem abaixo mostra o que cadas textbox faz, ele é o seletor de cor, cada vez que muda a cor ele recebe o valor.

[image: Tela de demostração]

---

Complemento de códigos para facilitar o entendimento.
Existe uma etapa que ele monta alguns JS para ser acionado assim que mudar o valor da TextBox:

```
txt.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript>");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel0.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel1.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel2.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel3.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel4.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel5.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel6.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel7.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel8.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("Corescolhe(" + txt_DetImovel9.ClientID + ");");
txt.Append("</script>");
```

e o JS

```
function Corescolhe(elemento) {
    $(elemento).spectrum({
        showPaletteOnly: false,
        className: "full-spectrum",
        showInitial: true,
        chooseText: "OK",
        cancelText: "cancelar",
        showPalette: true,
        preferredFormat: "hex",
        localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
        move: function (color) {
            updateBorders(color);
        },
        hide: function (color) {
            updateBorders(color);
            //  alert('irá mudar');
            $(elemento).val(color);
        }
};
```

**Porém o problema é que o JS realmente muda somente o TextoBox X porém todos os Textbox disparam o autopostBack ao mesmo tempo, se eu for debugando, vejo que a função txt_DetImovel0_TextChanged é chamada uma vez para cada componente e não para qual foi apenas mudado o valor!**

Comment: Não seria melhor migrar para HTML puro e usar ajax para controlar os salvamentos?

Comment: tentei..mas não deu...rs...até pq os valores, seja essa descrição, essas cores, etc..vem do banco de dados..é montado dinamicamente. tentei utilizar javascript manipulando o postback para tentar salvar apenas aquele elemento por vez, porém não deu muito certo..desse modo esta funcionando, porém editou uma cor, ele salva todas de novo..desperdício de recurso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em WebForms, você tem um formulario com varios controles.

Quando você define o autopostback em um dos controles, significa que o formulario inteiro será postado quando ocorrer um dos eventos assimilados no controle.

Isto não é bug, é o comportamento padrão do WebForms.

No seu caso, sugiro retirar o autopostback e eventos de todas as caixas de texto e adicionar um botão ao final do formulário para salvar. Ao clicar neste botão, todos os campos do formulário serão enviados, mas de uma vez só.

Comment: é uma boa opção, mas que o formulário ficaria menos inteligente do que o atual, ficaria, tentei fazer com javascript a manipulação dos elementos via postback e também não deu certo.

Comment: Dorathoto dei olha olhada melhor na sua pergunta, e realmente está errado. Deveria ser executado somente um POSTBACK para cada textbox alterada, e não 50 postbacks para cada alteração. Certamente o erro deve estar no seu javascript, coloque um trecho relevante do código que tentaremos lhe ajudar.

Comment: coloco onde o trecho do código nos comentários, edito a pergunta? ou adiciono uma resposta ?

Comment: Editando a pergunta